# gnome-shell or cinnamon: How do I pass the variable to the callback?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, callback, linux-mint, gnome-shell

I am trying to generate a dynamic pop up menu whereby the items in the list come from a json file.  I hope there are enough details here for you to make a judgment.

The simplified contents of the json are:

```
{
    "locationdetails" : {
        "type": "combobox",
        "default" : "Yellowstone",
        "description" : "Default starting location:",
        "options" : {
            "Death Valley" : "Death Valley",
            "Yellowstone" : "Yellowstone"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like a pop-up menu that has two menu items ("Yellowstone" and "Death Valley").  When either of these are clicked it would use the callback function to call another function with the correct variable passed (eg getLocation("Yellowstone") or getLocation("Death Valley")).

I have the following piece of code but it does not work correctly:

```
var output = "";
for ( var place in this.settings.metaBindings.locationdetails.settings_obj.json.locationdetails.options ) {
  output += place.toString()+"\n";
  this._menu.addAction(_(place.toString()), Lang.bind(this, function() {
  global.log(place.toString());  
}) );
};
global.log(output);
```

*this.settings.metaBindings.locationdetails.settings_obj.json.locationdetails.options* seems to be where I can access all the options in the json file.  (Let me know if there is a simpler way of getting this!)

For testing purposes I am logging what is passed when the for loop is processed in *output* and putting all the contents on the global error log.  At the moment when a menu item is clicked it just prints onto the log the place name passed to it (rather than calling another function).

When I use looking glass to verify what has happened I discover that:

1) Two menu items have been created, each with the correct label (Yellowstone or Death Valley)

2) *output* correctly outputs "Yellowstone" and "Death Valley"

3) Every time I click on the pop-up menu item, the log always prints "Yellowstone" even if I click on "Death Valley".  Further investigation shows it always prints whatever is the last option in my json file.

I am confused why the code correctly creates the pop-up menu item with the correct label but fails to pass the same label onto the callback.  I hope at least some of this makes sense!

What am I doing wrong?